# Serverless VoIP application

Tags: lan, voip

Can anybody recommend a serverless VoIP application?

I have a local network and require an application that will allow voice communications between all people connected to that LAN. The applications TeamSpeak and Mumble+Murmer allows communicating between nodes on a network but requires a central server to which all the nodes can connect. My LAN clients are moving around and it cannot be guaranteed that all clients will be able to see a single central server at all times, but wil hopefully be able to see some of it's other peer nodes. Is there any application that allows VOIP using Speex codec or similar with any peer connected on the same network? (ie without a central server)

An example will be Node A and Node B is connected to the network. They exchange voice messages between each other. Node C connects to the network and is able to communicate with A and B. If either A or B disconnects, Node C will still be able to send and receive voice messages with the remaining peer, A or B.

I need for all people on the network to be able to have voice comms, regardless of who is online or not.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Izzy. I have rephrased my question as you suggested. I can unfortunately not break it down into any simpler requirements since I only have two: VOIP and it must operate without a single central host. Hope the added example makes the question clearer.

Comment: Thanks, Christo! Mind to add the targeted OS? Should it be for Android or iOS, or rather for Laptops running on Linux or Windows – or must it even be cross-platform?